# How do you find by what percent a number is more or less than another number.

Tags: percentages, number-comparison

Lets say by what percent 50 is less than 100?

1. (100-50/100)*100
2. (100-50/50)*100

over here which of the following options are right `1` or `2`? and why?

By what percent 100 is more than 50?

1. (100-50/100)*100
2. (100-50/50)*100

over here which of the following options are right `1` or `2`? and why?

Comment: $$R = \frac{k}{100} \times S \implies k = \frac{100 R}{S}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x$ and $y$ are positive numbers,
\begin{equation}
100 \times \frac{y}{x}
\end{equation}
is the percentage of $x$ into $y$. For example
\begin{equation}
100\times \frac{99}{60} = 165
\end{equation}
hence 99 is 165% of 60. Similarly
\begin{equation}
100\times \frac{45}{60} = 75
\end{equation}
hence 45 is 75% of 60.
In order to get by what percentage $y$ is larger or smaller than $x$, simply remove 100, so
\begin{equation}
100\times\frac{y}{x} - 100
\end{equation}
For example 99 is $165 -100 = 65\%$ more than 60, and 45 is $75 - 100 = -25\%$ more than 60, that is to say 25% less than 60.